# Blank Page returned while consuming REST in ColdFusion 10 after page refresh

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I created a welcomemsg.cfc

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="welcomemsg">     
    <cffunction name="getMethod" access="remote" 
              returntype="String" httpmethod="GET"> 

        <cfset var kadal = "Welcome To HelloWorld!">
        <cfreturn kadal> 
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

I registered and mapped the CFC folder using the "Admin's REST Services" page. The following index.cfm was created to consume the REST Service:

```
<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8500/rest/mest/welcomemsg" method="get">
<cfoutput>#cfhttp.filecontent#</cfoutput>
```

When I run index.cfm, the result page is displayed as expected with "Welcome To HelloWorld!". But, when I refresh the page, a blank page is returned.
I restarted the web browser and tried accessing index.cfm. A blank page is returned again.

Kindly help.

Dev Env details:

- ColdFusion 10 Developer Edition
- Windows 7 64 bit
- Chrome 31.0
- No authentication used, No database connections used.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you just browse to your service from a browser?

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes! The problem exist even if I try the service directly from the browser.

Comment: Where us the CFC located, within webroot or in mapped folder?  and how have you added rest mapping in admin? Is there any error reported in server logs or when you refresh rest application (in admin). Also did you change the cfc and then refreshed the cfm page?

Comment: I just created everything locally as you described and it works without the problem you stated (only difference is Chrome 32).  I get a blank page if I type /rest/ followed by an invalid service mapping (eg., make sure 'mest' is your service mapping).

Comment: Also note that if you make any changes to your CFC (*any* changes),  you need to re-initialise the REST system, or you might see what you're seeing (but there will be errors in the error logs). This is completely cr@p on the part of Adobe, but... well... that's the quality of their work these days. See: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3915641

Answer (score 0):

@NaranRaj, did you ever resolve this? If not, I have a few thoughts (and even if you did, perhaps these may help future readers).

First, I would wonder if this "blank page" you get might have still more information than is apparent. For instance, what was the status code returned? You may not see that readily in your browser, but you could use browser dev tools to see the browser-server communication. You could also look in CF's logs for any errors.

But I have a guess as to the problem: you use port 8500. Is that how your CF is defined to be accessed? For instance, can you access the CF Admin that way? But I suspect you can.

Then the last question is: did you put your CF example code in the [cf10]\cfusion\wwwroot? or did you put it in your web server docroot? If the latter, you will get a blank page (with a 500 status code) if you try to access the URL with that 8500 port. You do NOT want to use that. If you use no port to access regular web pages in your web server docroot, don't use a port to access your REST services.

Let us know if that helps, or if future readers find that it helps.